# Is this a safe way to update a private variable in a closure?

Tags: javascript

Is this considered a safe way to update `privateVar` inside a closure?

```js
var test = (function() {
    var privateVar = "Hello";

    function returnPrivateVar() {
        return privateVar;
    }

    function returnWindowPrivateVar() {
        return window.test.privateVar;
    }

    return {
        returnPrivateVar: returnPrivateVar,
        returnWindowPrivateVar: returnWindowPrivateVar
    }
})();

var results = document.querySelector('#results');

results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + test.returnPrivateVar() + '<br>\n';
results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + test.returnWindowPrivateVar() + '<br>\n';

test.privateVar = "Goodbye";

results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + test.returnPrivateVar() + '<br>\n';
results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + test.returnWindowPrivateVar() + '<br>\n';
```

```html
<div id='results'></div>
```

I would ideally like to avoid using a getter/setter method. I just want to make sure that I can reliably call `window.test.privateVar` inside the test function. I understand I will probably have to ensure it is defined before using it.

Comment: If you could call `window.test.privateVar`, then it wouldn't be private.

Comment: if your privateVar is primitive or string you will have only copy, returning object you will expose reference to your variable in closure

Comment: `window.test.privateVar` does not exist.

Comment: `window.test.privateVar` works after `test.privateVar = "Goodbye";` in Chrome for me.